# Decision in Inspec profiles

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, inspec

I'm running a postgres inspec profile and would like to run certain tests only if the node is a master node. Here is my profile

```
sql = postgres_session('postgres', password, 'localhost')
result = describe sql.query('SELECT pg_is_in_recovery()') do
    its('output') { should eq 'f' }
end
if result == 'f'
   describe sql.query('SELECT state from pg_stat_replication') do
      its('output') { should match 'streaming' }
   end
end
```

But this doesn't work as the variable result doesn't store value 'f'.

My question is how do i store a value in a variable and use that for the next test in inspec ?
How do we print variable values in inspec (debug statements)

Comment: Which values does it store?

Comment: wanted to store the output of first command into a variable `result` and then based on this value run the second command.

Comment: In this case any ideas how do i print what is store in the variable `result` ?

Comment: Sorry, I was too terse. You complain that `result` does not contain `t` or `f`, right? So I wonder what it contains instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

speaking only from my memory, you should assign the sql query into a variable, pass that variable to the describe block so you could use the matcher (but it feels that you do not need it in your case), and then place a condition on that variable. it should be something like:

```rb
sql = postgres_session('postgres', password, 'localhost')
result = sql.query('SELECT pg_is_in_recovery()')

if result.output == 'f'
   describe sql.query('SELECT state from pg_stat_replication') do
      its('output') { should match 'streaming' }
   end
end
```